# Script run inside docker container reporting significantly higher memory than outside

Tags: php, docker, virtualbox

I am running a PHP cli script for a data import. It periodically checks its memory usage and if it approaches its limit, gracefully bombs out.

```
if ($percentage = (memory_get_usage() / ini_get('memory_limit')) > 0.95) {
      $message = sprintf("%s Memory used %d Mb of %d Mb", ImportException::MEMORY_LIMIT_REACHED, (memory_get_usage() / 1024/1024), (ini_get('memory_limit') / 1024/1024));
      $this->logger->emergency($message);
      throw new ImportException($message);
}
```

When ran via homebrew PHP CLI (v5.6.18) on OSX (El Capitan iMac 3.5Ghz i7), the script runs well and the memory usage never tops 100MB or so

[image]
Now, I am trying to run the script within a Docker container which is launched from a VirtualBox VM on the same iMac. The VirtualBox VM is given 2048MB of memory and the Docker container which runs the script also has the same.

[image: Virtualbox settings]

[image: Docker container launch script showing memory allocation]

[image: Docker stats showing high memory usage]

Crucially, the PHP script reports the same vastly inflated memory usage as the Docker stats and causes the script to bomb out early after consuming nearly 2GB. The PHP CLI version within the docker container is the same.

I am sure this must have something to do with the way docker translates memory usage reporting, which in turn is picked up by the http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php php reporting method. The process on the Mac does not show the high usage neither.

I just don't know enough about the intricacies of Virtualisation together with Docker. Is there a reliable system call i can use (via passthru()) to get the "real" memory usage?

As suggested, i installed  PHP within the same (Ubuntu 14.04) virtualbox VM that has docker and my container on. Running the script again shows the same behaviour as on OSX, i.e. memory usage never exceeding 100MB.

[image]

This image above shows top running whilst both the script being run within the docker container (1.306g) and the script running on the VM (~83Mb). Both processes are running the same script exactly (VM has mount via NFS and container has data volume on the VM).

I do see the following message when i start up the container (WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities, memory limited without swap.):

[image]